# How to serialize to XML an ArrayList

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble serializing an ArrayList into an XML in .NET. I am using ASP MVC and created a class which extends ActionResult

```
public class XmlResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly object _data;

    public XmlResult(object data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (_data != null)
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(_data.GetType(), "Assignment2.Models.Bl.Book");

            serializer.Serialize(response.OutputStream, _data);
        }
    }
}
```

Now _data is an ArrayList of ReportFVO

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Assignment2.Models.Bl.Book
{
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ReportFVO))]
    public class ReportFVO
    {
        public String title { get; set; }
        public String author { get; set; }
        public String first_name { get; set; }        
        public String last_name { get; set; }

        public ReportFVO()
        {
            this.title = "";
            this.author = "";
            this.first_name = "";
            this.last_name = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Every time XmlResult is called I get an exception saying "The type Assignment2.Models.Bl.Book.ReportFVO was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.". I am out of ideas. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using an ArrayList? That's sooo much deprecated since the introduction of generics. Use a `ReportFVO[]` or `List<ReportFVO>` instead. As an alternative you may try the following:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(_data.GetType(), new Type[] { typeof(ReportFVO) });
```